# How to count by x_user_id within {req:{headers:{x-user-id}}} in Grafana Loki

Tags: count, grafana-loki

I want to find out, how many different Users wrote a log within a given time-period. For that I wrote several queries in Grafana Loki. The results I get don't add up and I don't know where the problem in my query is.

The following Query gives me the different x-user-id and the number of logs they wrote in a given time-period:

```
count by(req_headers_x_user_id) (count_over_time({namespace="jx-production", app="api-api"} |= `x-user-id` | json [$__interval]))
```

When I add a second count around that to get the total amount of different x-user-ids the number I get doesn't match the number of different ids if I count them in the result of my first query (real value: 51. Value with second count: 9)

```
count(count by(req_headers_x_user_id) (count_over_time({namespace="jx-production", app="api-api"} |= `x-user-id` | json [$__interval])))
```

What is the problem with my second query and how can I fix it?

Comment: Your query looks fine. What do you mean by "different ids"? Your second query should simply return number "rows" that were returned by first one (which in turn should produce number of logs per user id).